# How to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} xe^{-x^2 \sin(t)}dt =0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} xe^{-x^2 \sin(t)}dt  =0$ by other methods. I know a proof using $\sin(t)\geq \frac {2t}{\pi},\forall t\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Comment: exactly, to show what?

Comment: limit equal to 0

Comment: What is wrong with that proof? It is very easy. One can do difficult things etc, but do you really want that?

Comment: If you know DCT you can get by with less detailed knowledge of the $\sin$ function.

Comment: @Shashi I said I'm looking for other ways

Comment: Okay, I already gave you another solution, however it is not as elementary as the one that you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x) = xe^{-\sin(t)x^2}$ has its maximum at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\sin(t)}}$  if $t\in(0,\pi/2)$ and $x>0$. So:
\begin{align}
|xe^{-\sin(t)x^2}|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\sin(t)}}e^{-1/2}
\end{align}
It is clear that $$\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\sin(t)}}e^{-1/2} dt < \infty $$
Since the function  behaves like $Ct^{-1/2}$ near $t=0$. Now DCT gives the required result, namely:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} xe^{-\sin(t)x^2}\, dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} \lim_{x\to\infty} xe^{-\sin(t)x^2}\, dt = \int^{\pi/2}_0 0\, dt =0
\end{align}

**Edit**.

Since the OP asks for more methods, I'll give a method that looks a little bit as the one given in the comments below by @Tina. I use asymptotics. Note that the main contribution is near $t=0$ hence (you can make this argument more  rigourous!):
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 xe^{-x^2\sin(t)}\,dt \sim \int^{\pi/2}_0 xe^{-x^2t}\,dt \sim  \int^{\infty}_0 xe^{-x^2t}\,dt = \frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
as $x\to\infty$. This method does not only give you that it goes to zero, but it shows you that it goes to zero as $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @ Shashi thank you a very nice method too,  can we also apply the monotonous convergence theorem ?

Comment: @Tina To apply MCT, you need a monotone function.  Perhaps you want $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: No I don't think so, because the function $f(x)$ that I have defined above is not monotone in $x$

Comment: I don't understand where the argument of the sine came from

Comment: @Shashi  $\forall t\in [x^{-\frac{3}2}, \pi /2],\quad \sin(t)\geq \sin(x^{-\frac{3}2})$

Comment: Typo $\int_0^{\pi /2} f(x,t)dt=\int_0^{x^{-3/2}} f(x,t)dt+ \int_{x^{-3/2}}^{\pi /2} f(x,t)dt\leq x\int_0^{x^{-3/2}} 1dt + (\pi/2-x^{-3/2} ) x e^{(-x^2 \sin(x^{-3/2} ) )}=x^{-1/2} + (\pi/2-x^{-3/2} ) x e^{(-x^2 \sin(x^{-3/2} ) )}\to 0$

Comment: @Shashi Draw the graph of $\sin x$ for the 1st quadrant and use a straight line to link up the two end points.

Comment: @Tina now I understand. Nice!!

Comment: @all  So far, we have 3 methods, do you know other methods ?

Comment: @Tina I added one more.

Comment: @Shashi I like this last method because it shows  for example $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^2.e^{-x^2 \sin(t)}dt  =1$ 
while other methods fail ( we can only show by the three previous methods tha $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^a.e^{-x^2 \sin(t)}dt  =0$  if $a<2$

Comment: @Shashi  To prove rigorously $\displaystyle \forall a>0,  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-x^a \sin(t)}\, dt\sim \frac 1{x^a}$ we can put $s=x^a t$ , thus $\displaystyle \forall a>0,  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-x^a \sin(t)}\, dt=\frac 1{x^a}\int_0^{+\infty} 1_{[0,+\infty[} e^{-x^a \sin(\frac s{x^a})}\, ds $ and $\int_0^{+\infty} 1_{[0,+\infty[} e^{-x^a \sin(\frac s{x^a})}\, ds  \to_{By\, DCT} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-s}ds=1$

Comment: @Tina that's very neat!

Comment: Typo to replace  $1_{[0,+\infty[}$ by $1_{[0, \frac {\pi  x^a}2[}$

Answer (score 2):

**New proof**: Note that

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}xe^{-x^2\sin t}\, dt \le \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}xe^{-x^2/\sqrt 2}\, dt \to 0.$$

On $[0,\pi/4]$ we can let $t=\arcsin u$ to get

$$\int_0^{1/\sqrt 2}\frac{xe^{-x^2u}}{(1-u^2)^{1/2}}\, du \le \int_0^{1/\sqrt 2}xe^{-x^2u}\sqrt 2\, du,$$

and it's easy to show the last integral $\to 0.$

**Previous proof**: The concavity of $\sin t$ shows $\sin t \ge 2t/\pi$ on the interval $[0,\pi/2].$ Thus the integral in question is bounded above by $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} xe^{-2x^2t/\pi}dt.$ Let $t = u/x^2.$ Then the last integral equals

$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x^2\pi /2} e^{-2u/\pi}\,du < \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2u/\pi}\,du .$$

Since the last integral is finite, we see our integral is less than a constant times $\frac{1}{x},$ hence $\to 0.$

Comment: This is the first method I described above

Comment: Right, I didn't read that part.

Comment: @Tina I added a new proof.

Comment: Okey , nice proof again